# Android - When to clear cache?

Tags: android, caching

I have an Android app where I'm grabbing images from a server, storing them in the cache, and then inserting them into a list view. These images are updated every week or so on the server so I have to clear the cache for my app to have the most recent image.

I don't want to clear the cache every time the app closes because it takes a little time to load the images from the server.

I already know how to clear the cache but am unsure on the appropriate time. It doesn't seem appropriate when the user simply clicks the back button on the app. I was thinking when the user swipes the app from the 'multitasker' menu on their phone but can't find how to handle that event.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a 'version number' of the image on client and on the server. If your server image version is different than your client version, load from server. This will cost a lot less time loading and its the exact timing you will need to load your image.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a design constraint. The app is being used by multiple organizations so they each have their own unique id on the server that they overwrite the image for. I can't afford to increment the counter every time a new image is uploaded due to size constraints.

Comment: Not sure about the limitations you are refering to. Is it the 32 bit counter size you are worrying about or do you just need to account for the organization Id associated with its 'version number'?